# Outputting if the last command was a successful git checkout

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to echo to the console in the event that a successful git checkout happened, but cannot get it to work.

```
function prompt_command {
   prev=`fc -ln -1`
   ecode=$?

   if [ ecode = 0 ]
   then
      if [ `echo $prev | grep -c "^git co -b"` -ge 0 ] || [ echo $prev | `grep -c "^git checkout -b"` -ge 0 ]
      then
        echo "SUCCESSFULLY CHECKED OUT!"
      fi
   fi
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

---

**Context:**
The eventual aim is to update the new git branch's description to indicate which branch it was checked out from. E.g. If I checkout "my_new_feature" from "dev", I want to automatically run:
`git config branch.my_new_feature.description "[FROM:dev]"`

Then modify the prompt to include the *parent* branch.

Comment: `[ ecode = 0 ]` should be `[[ $ecode -eq 0 ]]`

Comment: Or ``[ "$ecode" = 0 ]``.

Answer (score 1):

`[ ecode = 0 ]` should be `[[ "$ecode" -eq 0 ]]`:

- [Double brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/669486/96588)
- [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- Use a dollar sign in front of variables to expand them (`[[` is a special case where you don't strictly need dollar signs or quotes in this case)
- Use `-eq` for integer comparison